# nginx port opened inside but closed outside

Tags: nginx

I made nginx setup. I bound it to the 3200 port (just to check)

When I do *netstat -pnltu* on server

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::3200                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I see nginx is really listening on port 3200

But if I try *nmap mysite.ru* (real name hidden for security reasons)

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Actually port 3200 is NOT LISTENING.

I'm on Centos 7 and do not have either SELinux or any firewall enabled.

As for nginx configuration I only added in nginx.conf

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
listen      3200 default_server;
    listen      [::]:3200 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

After default *include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;* string

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked a firewall (ufw or similar)?

Comment: no ufw in..., sudo firewall-cmd --state not running, getenforce Disabled

Comment: It's not my own server, but you see I made usual checks for security (though I'm rather developer than admin and there may be others)

Comment: Maybe you need to open that port on your hosting provider. This also could be the reason.